Who passes argument inside the entrypoint! macro?
solana's fn entrypoint(input: *mut u8) receives a pointer, who passes this argument and when? Is this argument stored in MM_INPUT_START region of the rbpf VM?

The runtime will pass this pointer to the function called entrypoint in your program, and if you print the address of this pointer:
  use solana_program::msg;
  #[no_mangle]
  pub unsafe extern "C" fn entrypoint(input: *mut u8) -> u64 {
      msg!("{:p}", input);
      0
  }

You'll get the address of 0x400000000 which is MM_INPUT_START
More information at https://solana.com/docs/programs/lang-rust#program-entrypoint
Note: I wrote a little zig program to do this with https://github.com/joncinque/solana-sdk-zig since it was simpler than getting the Rust one to work, here's the source
const sol = @import("sol");
export fn entrypoint(input: [*]u8) u64 {
    sol.print("Hello program {*}", .{input});
    return 0;
}


Thanks for the info, but do you where is this code in solana-sdk?

Certainly, here's the entrypoint macro code in the sdk: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/b0cfffb290051d8c8a42923eca1459e3bba4cef2/sdk/program/src/entrypoint.rs#L125

apologies for not clarifying, I meant the code which invokes the entrypoint function present inside this macro.

Ah gotcha, here's the code that executes the VM in the runtime https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/8f694bacd23b00d43f808dbb90696ecc5e1bdd00/programs/bpf_loader/src/lib.rs#L1398 and then the VM code that sets the programs entrypoint as the first executed instruction at https://github.com/solana-labs/rbpf/blob/ec42f0274dabccf25331555805053203e130906a/src/vm.rs#L375
